# Change text on shape

Tags: android, text, shapes, andengine

Hi
  is it possible to change the text of a shape? I have:

```
levelFraction = new Text(0, 300, mFont, "text", HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
```

then I add it to the scene:

```
scene.getTopLayer().addEntity(levelFraction);
```

but I don't see any method to change the text at runtime. Something like:

```
levelFraction.setText(...);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What kind of object do you get from `new Text(...)`? I can't seem to find any class `Text` in the references http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html...

Comment: could you provide a link to this `Text` class that is a subclass of `Shape` perhaps? It might be that I'm just missing something obvious, but the only subclasses of `Shape` I can find are `ArcShape`, `OvalShape`, `PathShape`, `RectShape` and `RoundRectShape` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html).

Comment: It's a class from a framework I use, andengine. Mmm, better if I report it to andengine's developers perhaps.

Comment: That wasn't clear at all. You could probably get help here, but you definitely need to improve your question. I have re-tagged it, adding the *andengine* tag. You should yourself edit your question to make it more clear which class(es) you are using (and that they belong to the AndEngine framework), how you're using them, what you're trying to do etc. I also recommend you reading John Skeet's guide to asking the perfect question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about the AndEngine library, so this would just be a wild guess:

Could you perhaps use the `ChangeableText` (which extends `Text`) instead of `Text`? From the name it sounds like you should be able to change the text, and looking at the code it also have a couple of functions to set the text: [ChangeableText source](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/text/ChangeableText.java)

Comment: It's perfect for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if Sheet1.shapes(0).texteffect.text="Go" then
   sheet1.shapes(0).texteffect.text="Stop"
else
   sheet1.shapes(0).texteffect.text="Go"
end if
```

You could even call a sub based on the the value of the texteffect.text

Answer (score 0):

```
font_texture_golbalValue = new Texture(128,64,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
font4 = new Font(font_texture_golbalValue, Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD), textSize, true, Color.WHITE);
this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.font_texture_golbalValue);
this.mEngine.getFontManager().loadFont(this.font4);
scoreval=new ChangeableText(24*CAMERA_WIDTH/100, score_postion, this.font2, ""+scoreValue,"Score##".length());
```

and You can use scorevalue.SetText();